# Nginx match multiple paths in location directive

Tags: nginx, regex

I have the following directives in my nginx conf, that are working correctly:

```
location = /favicon.ico {
    root /home/www/myapp/static/ico;
}


location ^~ /apple-touch-icon  {
    root /home/www/myapp/static/ico;
}
```

I would to merge those expression in one directive but I cant figure out how to correctly build the regex. I tried the following but it works only for favicon.ico and I get 404 requesting /apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png

```
location ~* ^/(apple-touch-icon(.)*\.png|favicon.ico) {
    root /home/www/myapp/static/ico;
}
```

It is a problem of what is matched I think.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex works fine on my server. Maybe the file `/home/www/myapp/static/ico/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png` just doesn't exist ?

P.S. The exact translation of your old rules into a regex is:

```
^/(apple-touch-icon|favicon.ico$)
```

P.P.S. If you have no other `.png` and `.ico` images at the top-level you could use:

```
^/[^/]+\.(png|ico)$
```